# How can I use a php array in my sql query?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to use an array in my sql query.

Could someone help me please ?

```
$categories = [256, 249, 681, 682, 683, 684];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`category` WHERE `id_category` = (:categories);";    
$request= $database->prepare($sql);    
$request->bindValue(':categories', $categories, PDO::PARAM_INT);    
$request->execute();    
$result = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The value returned from my array is 1, how can I explode my array in my SQL request ?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `IN` keyword which takes a comma separated list. To make it prepared replace any value with a `?` placeholder, so the query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM `database`.`category` WHERE `id_category` IN (?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

Instead of binding each value to a variable, you can pass the values directly to `execute()`.

```
$categories = [256, 249, 681, 682, 683, 684];
$catQuery = implode(',', array_map(fn($x) => '?', $categories));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `database`.`category` WHERE `id_category` IN ($catQuery);";
$request= $database->prepare($sql);
$request->execute($categories);
$result = $request->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```